# How can I restore sockets in rooms after Redis crashes with socket.io/redis-adapter

Tags: javascript, redis, socket.io

I've made a project in node.js that uses `socket.io` and `socket.io/redis-adapter` to connect multiple sockets and manage them in Redis. I'm looking to make it so that if Redis ever crashed entirely, it's state could be rebuilt by using the active sockets.

I've got a working server so far with

```js
  const pubClient = createClient({
    url: redisAddress,
  });
  pubClient.on('error', error => {
    Logger.error(error);
  });
  const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();
  subClient.on('error', error => {
    Logger.error(error);
  });
  Promise.all([pubClient.connect(), subClient.connect()]).then(() => {
    io.adapter(createAdapter(pubClient, subClient));
...
```

and once I have these connected everything works great, and other services can emit to Redis and the connected devices will receive those instructions.

When Redis goes down I have observed that the socket server reconnects to Redis when available, but Redis has lost all of the connection information it had. If I force the sockets to reconnect they seem to be added to rooms (named the same as they were before) but emits to those rooms don't get to the devices.

I'm guessing that Redis is storing a cache of some kind on the gateway that I need to clear if and when the Redis connection fails; how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is kind of flawed. Socket.io redis adapter handles this, and the issue I was having was caused by the redis client not finishing the reconnect operation on the subClient. Currently downgrading the redis package to v3.1.2 works without further changes.